# Angularjs include a template from another page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, templates, angularjs-ng-include

I've got a template in a html page to include in another page. This is because the two html are very long and i can't use only one page to both. So i decided to separate them. Summary this is my case:

in partials/template.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate">
    myTemplate..
</script>
```

and in partials/my_layout.html

```
<ng-include src="'./partials/template.html'"></div>
```

But it's not working now. Nothing is showing when the page is loaded. How can i access to the template of the `template.html` page?

Answer (score 1):

Its likely a relative path issue. The path should be from index.html to your template, not the path from one template to another. Try something like this:

`<ng-include src="'partials/template.html'"></div>`

EDIT

I just noticed this was a script template. The id that you give the template is the key that you can use to access it in the src of the ng-include. Try this:

`<ng-include src="'myTemplate'"></div>`

Comment: Yes but it's in another html file. In this way it doesn't recognize the id of the template.. If myTemplate was in the same page of the ng-inlcude then yes, it worked. But in this way nope

Comment: Ok, try pulling the template http out into a separate file (with no script tags around it). Then ng-include a path to that file in both places you need to use it